Strong convergence of Euler-Maruyama for solving non-homogenous SDE
I am struggling to find a reference or proof of the strong convergence of Euler-Maruyama for solving the following time non-homogenous SDE:
$$dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
All books I can find, such as the book by Peter E. Kloeden and Eckhard Platen, only consider cases of homogenous SDE.
I would greatly appreciate any references or insights on this matter.

I suggest looking into Pagès, Ch. 7.
